# sub query not evaluating parameter correctly

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Needed to start a new thread to deal with a new issue from old problem.

Original problem is at this link....
[complex query join checking that value does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992879/complex-query-join-checking-that-value-does-not-exist)

I have two tables, first has

```
Tb1 = drID, schedDate, rteID
```

Second has:

```
Tb2  = drID, FName, LName, Active
```

tb1 schedDate has a value for 11/12/2012 but returns no records, if I enter 11/01/2012 I get the correct records back, but this date does not exist on any record in tb1.

```
SELECT drID, Fname, LName
FROM   TB2
WHERE  Active = True 
AND   drID NOT IN (
      SELECT drID
      FROM   Tb1
      WHERE  (drID IS NULL OR drID = '')
      AND  (schedDate = (@targetDate)
      )
```

Both date fields are dates I have tried casting each individually and both together as in...

```
AND (CAST(schedDate AS DATE) = CAST(@targetDate AS DATE))
```

and

```
AND (CAST(schedDate AS DATETIME) = CAST(@targetDate AS DATETIME))
```

I am trying to check that no drID exists in tb1 on the date submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the correct solution for this question....

```
WHERE not exists (SELECT drID FROM tb1 ....
```

Date values where not the issue.

Thanks for all of the feed back.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a fundamental flaw in your subquery:

```
SELECT drID, Fname, LName
FROM   TB2
WHERE  Active = True 
AND   drID NOT IN (
  -- You are looking for drID's not included in the following subquery.
  SELECT drID
  FROM   Tb1
  WHERE  (drID IS NULL OR drID = '')
  AND  (schedDate = (@targetDate)
  )
```

Your subquery **only** returns null or '' drID's.

```
  SELECT drID
  FROM   Tb1
  WHERE  (drID IS NULL OR drID = '')
  AND  (schedDate = (@targetDate)
```

edit:

To be more clear, the outer query returns all drID, Fname, LName from table2 where the active flag is set to true and the drID **IS NOT INCLUDED IN** the list of drID's **returned by the sub query**.  Your sub query never returns a drID.

Remove the (drID IS NULL or dirID = '') from the sub query.

Comment: From all of this I need to return from TB2 drID, Fname, LName Where Active = True and drID does not exist on any record in tb1 for the schedDate selected.

There are many tb1 rteID records for any possible date.

Comment: The NOT IN portion of the main query takes care of filtering out any drID's that exist in the second query.

Comment: I made those changes and it still does not work unless there is at least one record to be excluded by matching a drID from TB2. If Tb1 has no records on the submitted date there is nothing returned at all, when this should actually return all drIDs from TB2.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove any hour, mins secs and smaller time information from the two datetime variables before the compare.

```
SELECT drID, Fname, LName
FROM   TB2
WHERE  Active = True 
AND   drID NOT IN (
      SELECT drID
      FROM   Tb1
      WHERE  (drID IS NULL OR drID = '')
      AND  (dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,schedDate),0) = 
            dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,@targetDate),0)
           )
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
SELECT drID, Fname, LName
FROM   TB2 left outer join tb1 on
  tb2.drid = tb1.drid and
  tb1.active = true and
  schedDate = @targetDate
WHERE  
  tb1.drid is null
```

if it's the date test for equality that's causing it to fail, you could also try

```
where abs(datediff(day,@targetDate,schedDate)) < 1
```

Comment: What if datediff returns -2?  (Then your solution fails)

Comment: added `abs()`  I really don't know if that's the problem, tho

Comment: From all of this I need to return from TB2 drID, Fname, LName Where Active = True and drID does not exist on any record in tb1 for the schedDate selected.

There are many tb1 rteID records for any possible date.